# Redimensioning array of ranges into a single array containing only the values of each range element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have multiple worksheets with ranges which I collect into an array of ranges, and I cant do `Union` since it does not work across worksheets.
Since I want to create a chart where the time-series or `FullSeriesCollection` are based on the elements of my combined ranges, I thought that redimensioning the array of ranges into a single array might serve as my solution.
Perhaps there is an easier solution that I am not seeing.

I tried to outline the general case below. The ranges are dynamic in my code, but here I just set them arbitrarily.

```
Sub Collection()

Dim arrDate() As Variant
Dim arrRngTotal As Variant
Dim rng_1 As Range, rng_2 As Range, rng_3 As Range
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer

Set ws_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set ws_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
' Example of ranges, not static in the original code.
Set rng_1 = ws_1.Range("A2:A10")
Set rng_2 = ws_1.Range("A11:A22")
Set rng_3 = ws_2.Range("A2:A22")

arrRngTotal = Array(rng_1.Value, rng_2.Value, rng_3.Value)


For k = LBound(arrRngTotal, 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal, 1)
    For j = LBound(arrRngTotal(k), 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal(k), 1)
            ReDim Preserve arrDate(j)
            arrDate(j) = arrRngTotal(k)(j, 1)
    Next j
Next k

End Sub
```

When I use this code I get an array with 22 elements corresponding to the range of `rng_3`. What I want to end up with after the nested loop is an array that contains the elements from all ranges in 1 single array with 1 dimension.

The reason I want this in the end is I want to create chart using the array values.

Comment: Why don't you just loop once for your range and add all the values at once? You can copy the ranges one after another in a temporal sheet, then loop through this new range once and add all the values without using the redim preserve, dimension it after copying the ranges.

Comment: You mean add a third sheet, copy the ranges from worksheet 1 and 2 and define the new range from that?

Comment: Yes, and then delete that sheet. Would take less time and code.

Comment: Or combine the arrays?

Comment: You are using `j` as a variable for your 1D array, but `j` does get reset on each outer loop iteration, hence the issue. Just need an additional variable as an independent counter... see my answer reusing your code, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, the only error is that you are reusing the same variable from your inner loop, which would reset on each outer loop. To get around that, just use an additional variable as such:

```vb
Sub Collection()

Dim arrDate() As Variant
Dim arrRngTotal As Variant
Dim rng_1 As Range, rng_2 As Range, rng_3 As Range
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, X As Long

Set ws_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set ws_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
' Example of ranges, not static in the original code.
Set rng_1 = ws_1.Range("A2:A10")
Set rng_2 = ws_1.Range("A11:A22")
Set rng_3 = ws_2.Range("A2:A22")

arrRngTotal = Array(rng_1.Value, rng_2.Value, rng_3.Value)


For k = LBound(arrRngTotal, 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal, 1)
    For j = LBound(arrRngTotal(k), 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal(k), 1)
            X = X + 1                       'Add an additional counter
            ReDim Preserve arrDate(X)
            arrDate(X) = arrRngTotal(k)(j, 1)
    Next j
Next k

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** slight variation, to improve the speed as per @Tom suggestion... see comments for further details.

```vb
Sub Collection()

Dim arrDate() As Variant: ReDim arrDate(1 To 1)
Dim arrRngTotal As Variant
Dim rng_1 As Range, rng_2 As Range, rng_3 As Range
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, X As Long

Set ws_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set ws_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
' Example of ranges, not static in the original code.
Set rng_1 = ws_1.Range("A2:A10")
Set rng_2 = ws_1.Range("A11:A22")
Set rng_3 = ws_2.Range("A2:A22")

arrRngTotal = Array(rng_1.Value, rng_2.Value, rng_3.Value)

'Dimension the holding array outside the main data loop, unless you need to do this inside based on various conditions
For k = LBound(arrRngTotal, 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal, 1)
    X = X + UBound(arrRngTotal(k))
Next k
ReDim Preserve arrDate(1 To X): X = 0

For k = LBound(arrRngTotal, 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal, 1)
    For j = LBound(arrRngTotal(k), 1) To UBound(arrRngTotal(k), 1)
            X = X + 1
            arrDate(X) = arrRngTotal(k)(j, 1)
    Next j
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: This works. Do you know how to prevent the first element to being empty `arrDate(0)` has the value `Empty` in my watch window.

Comment: Redim the array to start at 1 (or whatever number) `ReDim Preserve arrDate(1 to X)`, or alternatively move `X = X + 1` under the redim, though i prefer the first option, as it gives me more control over the index.

Comment: Your `ReDim Preserve` is going to slow this down massively with large data sets

Comment: @Tom That could be easily avoided by getting a sum of all `Ubound(arrRngTotal(k))` and redim the array before hand, since there are no inner ifs to populate the array at certain conditions only. Though for the size of the given sample, this should be just about fine anyways.

Comment: @DarXyde yup agreed, but you aren't doing it

Comment: @Tom I've made the simplest correction to an already working code... at the same time answering the question as well. Is there room for improvement? Sure it is, anything and everything we do, can be and should be revisited. The OP can surely take our comments into account if wishes to do so, will make the changes himself, or post another question. It was already accepted as an answer, but if it makes you feel any better, I will add your suggested change.

Comment: @DarXyde Don't take it quite so personally - I was more stating it for the OP's information rather than yours.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Collection()

    Dim arrDate As Variant
    Dim ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, j As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set ws_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)


    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        .Range("A1").Resize(ws_1.Range("A2:A10").Rows) = ws_1.Range("A2:A10").Value
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & LastRow).Resize(ws_1.Range("A11:A22").Rows) = ws_1.Range("A11:A22").Value
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & LastRow).Resize(ws_2.Range("A2:A22").Rows) = ws_2.Range("A2:A22").Value
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        j = 1
        ReDim arrDate(1 To LastRow)
        For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
            arrDate(j) = C
        Next C
        .Delete
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You could populate arrDate in one fell swoop without looping.

Comment: Yeah I know @SJR but he wants a 1D array, doing the `arrDate = Range.value` returns a 2D array, so I wasn't sure if that would fullfill OP's needs.

Comment: You can `Transpose` the range to convert it to a `1D` array in one line. `arrDate = Application.Transpose(Range.value)`. This is limited to values of 255 characters. [linky](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-excel-how-to-convert-range-to-array-easily/)

Comment: That works if your data is in rows. for data stored across multiple columns you can double `Transpose` i.e. `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(....` Or another trick is you can use `Index` to slice a range/array as show here [linky](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/)

Comment: @Tom I did try what is in the link and `arrKPI = Application.Index(MiArray, 0, 4)` still gives me a 2D array, not 1D. I want to use them for CountIF but needs to be 1D.

Comment: @Damian apologies may have confused things with the `Index` tip. `Index` will return part of an array but will return a `2D` one. To get a `1D` use `arrKPI = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(MiArray, 0, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to combine all arrays into one

```
Sub Collection()

    Dim arrDate() As Variant
    Dim arrRngTotal As Variant
    Dim rng_1 As Range, rng_2 As Range, rng_3 As Range
    Dim ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, arrCounter As Long

    Set ws_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    ' Example of ranges, not static in the original code.
    Set rng_1 = ws_1.Range("A2:A10")
    Set rng_2 = ws_1.Range("A11:A22")
    Set rng_3 = ws_2.Range("A2:A22")

    With Application
        arrRngTotal = Array(.Transpose(rng_1.Value), .Transpose(rng_2.Value), .Transpose(rng_3.Value))
    End With

    For k = LBound(arrRngTotal) To UBound(arrRngTotal)
        On Error Resume Next
        arrCounter = IIf(IsNumeric(UBound(arrDate)), UBound(arrDate), 0)
        arrCounter = arrCounter + GetArraySize(arrRngTotal(k))
        On Error GoTo 0
        ReDim Preserve arrDate(1 To arrCounter)

        For j = LBound(arrRngTotal(k)) To UBound(arrRngTotal(k))
            Debug.Print UBound(arrDate) - (UBound(arrRngTotal(k)) - j), arrRngTotal(k)(j)
            arrDate(UBound(arrDate) - (UBound(arrRngTotal(k)) - j)) = arrRngTotal(k)(j)
        Next j
    Next k

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetArraySize(arr As Variant) As Long
    GetArraySize = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
End Function
```